# Constructing immutable dictionary with inner immutable dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, immutable-collections

I have the following dictionary and wish to make it immutable;

```
var dict = ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action>>
```

I then call

```
var immmutableDict = dict.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

However this would still give the internal `ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action>` dictionary i believe.

How can i make an immutable copy of the entire dictionary in a thread safe fashion with existing functions, or would i need to lock the entire operation to ensure atomic conversion?

```
ImmutableDictionary<Type, ImmutableDictionary<Type, Action>>
```

Alternatively if the above is not possible, i can refactor code to use an ReadOnlyDictionary dictionary from the start, however i face the same challenge with the inner dictionary to make it read only during construction:

```
var dict2 = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, InstanceProducer>>();
/* snip perform adds to above dictionary to initialise state */

var immutableDict = dict2.ReadOnlyDictionary(); // ????
// where ReadOnlyDictionary<Type, ReadOnlyDictionary<Type, InstanceProducer>>(); is returned
// i need to make the above immutable with an immutable internal dictionary
```

Comment: What do you mean with "thread safe fashion" and "atomic conversion"? Do you mean that you want the resulting nested `ImmutableDictionary` to contain a snapshot of the initial nested `ConcurrentDictionary`? If you want snapshot semantics, then the only way to get them is by calling the method `ConcurrentDictionary.ToArray`. The `ToImmutableDictionary` extension method operates on `IEnumerable` interfaces, so it doesn't produce a snapshot. The resulting `ImmutableDictionary` may contain entries that were never co-existing in the initial collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert each of the internal dictionaries into immutable dictionaries as well, and then make a new ImmutableDictionary from those.

```
ImmutableDictionary<Type, ImmutableDictionary<Type, Action>> immutableDict = dict
    .ToImmutableDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value.ToImmutableDictionary());
```

Answer (score 1):

> However this would still give the internal ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action> dictionary i believe.

Calling:

```cs
var immmutableDict = dict.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

will result of creating a type: `ImutableDictionary<Type,  ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action>`, so it will not be the `ConcurrentDictionary`.

> How can i make an immutable copy of the entire dictionary in a thread safe fashion with existing functions, or would i need to lock the entire operation to ensure atomic conversion?

To understand how `dict.ToImmutableDictionary()` works lets read the official documentation, which says:

> Enumerates a sequence of key/value pairs and produces an immutable dictionary of its contents.

Does this thread-safe?
Yes, because `ImmutableDictionary` is a thread-safe and creating one from `ConcurrentDictionary` should also be thread-safe.

However, it's worth asking yourself another question:

- Why could I need this?

The reason for this question is the word **Immutable**, which means that it will create a new instance of the data each time when the modification will happen.

Taking into account that multi-threading means multiple thread access for possibly changing the data (unless you know that it will not be changed), it can become a really big performance hit.

Comment: Thanks Arsen for the time, i understand the `ImutableDictionary<Type,  ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action>` would be returned but with this the inner ConcurrentDictionary reference would still be modifiable. This can get very messy, then i realized a workaround using ReadOnly dictionary i just need to be able to initialize it first and then "lock" it but same issue with the inner dictionary.

Comment: I understand your concerns. Well, if you have a control for the dictionary initialization part, I would suggest replacing the `ConcurrentDictionary` with `ImutableDictionary` even in the initialization because both thread-safe, you don't need to worry about the concurrency here. However, if you don't have access to the initialization part, then you have to iteration through the dictionary and convert it item by item.